# Send anonymous type from controller to service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method like this in service:

```
 public Task SendAsync(string email, string subject, string message, string template)
        {
            Execute(email, subject, message, template).Wait();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

and I call it like this in controller:

```
  await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Confirm Email", callbackurl, englishFileContent);
```

That I want to do is to create string array like this:

```
  var englishArray = new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                         UrlTexT=  callbackurl,
                         HeaderText = "Header"
                         WelcomeText = "Welcome",
                         VerifyText = "Please verify your email address.",
                         VerifyText2 = "Verify2",
                         Footer = "Footer"
                    }
                };
```

and just send like this:

```
await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Confirm Email", englishArray, englishFileContent);
```

and service like:

```
 public Task SendAsync(string email, string subject, string[] message, string template)
        { ....}
```

But I receive:

> cannot convert from anonymous type: string UrlTexT, string HeaderText,
>   string WelcomeText, string VerifyText, string VerifyText2, string
>   Footer[] to string

How can I do this in correct way? Regards

Comment: Your sending an anonymous object, not an array of strings. The parameter would need to be `object message`

Comment: But you would be far better off just creating a class with those properties, and passing an instance of that class.

Comment: and how can I access this  properties in service? I mean something like message.UrlTexT, why I can't do it? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Because its an anonymous object (you do not get any strong typing). Just create a class for it.

Comment: And stop calling .Wait on things. Mark the method as async and await it instead.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I use class as your comment and  it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create a class rather than sending anonymous object. But if you don't want to use class then better you go with Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> message = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "UrlTexT", callbackurl},
    { "HeaderText", "Header"},
    { "WelcomeText", "Welcome"},
    { "VerifyText", "Please verify your email address."},
    { "VerifyText2", "Verify2" },
    { "Footer", "Footer" }
};

await _emailService.SendAsync(user.Email, "Confirm Email", message, englishFileContent);
```

and your service is

```
public async Task SendAsync(string email, string subject, Dictionary<string, object> message, string template)
{
    ...
}
```